# Intersection of 2 bidimensional arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to determine the intersection of 2 bi-dimensional arrays.

Here is my code:

```
#include < iostream >
using namespace std; 

void type(int mat[][10],int n)
{
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
      cin>>mat[i][j];
}

void inter(int a[][10], int n,int b[][10],int m)
{
  int k1=0,p, x,ok,j, c[50],i;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
      p=0; x=0;
      while(p<m)
      {  
        ok=0;
        while(x<m)
        {
          if(a[i][j]==b[p][x]) ok=1;
          if(ok) c[k1++]=a[i][j];
            x++;
        }
        p++;
      }
      for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
        cout<<c[i]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;}
      } 
    }
  }
}  // !!! added in edit!!!

int main()
{
  int n,m,mat[10][10],c[30],mat2[10][10];
  cout<<"n= ";cin>>n; 
  type(mat,n);
  cout<<"m= "; cin>>m;
  type(mat2,m); 
  inter(mat,n,mat2,m);
  return 0;
}
```

It doesn't show me the expected answer. It shoes me numbers like these : *1
4758024
1
4758024* 
Can somebody help me?

Comment: What's the error?  You also have issues that if you compile with maximum warnings on the compiler will tell you about.

Comment: Start really small. Instead of 10x10 matricies, start with 2x2 matricies. Then scale it up.

Comment: I improved the code formatting and some formulations and added a closing brace `}`.

Comment: You still need to edit the question to add the actual errors -- "it doesn't work" is not a useful error.  Please read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve]

Comment: I see that you have not provided the value of `m` in your `main()`

Comment: @SuhaibAhmad I modified

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Comment: First of all if you are using C++ you have a Boolean type and you don't need to declare all variables on the beginning of the code block. Second use more meaning full names for variables. Third, you have a constant size of the arrays and initialise only parts of them, moreover if you insert n and m bigger than 10 it will crash. And finally about your algorithm - is clearing of the `ok` variable fine if done only for a new row of the second array?